# mysql use CASE to update multiple rows with a for loop

Tags: mysql, loops, case

I need to update 360 rows. obviously this doesn't work properly. Any help, please

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 360; $i++) {

  $info  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$i]);
  $check = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[''.$i.'Check']);

      $case = "WHEN '$i' THEN '$info'";
}

  $sql = "UPDATE $table
            SET info = CASE id
              $case
            END
           WHERE ID in (1-360)";

  mysql_query($sql)
      or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: 1. "doesn't work" is not explanation 2. give plain sql query, without php at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's at least one (not very?) obvious reason why this doesn't work - you're replacing the contents of $case with every iteration of the loop. `$case .= "WHEN '$i' THEN '$info'\n";` (note the dot before the equal sign) might already get you further. Another one is probably that $i is put in single quotes inside the query while ID columns tend to be numeric.

I didn't try and run your code. If it still "doesn't work", you should edit your question and add more info like table structure and error messages.

Apart from that, you could do:

```
$sql = "UPDATE $table  SET\n";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 360; $i++) {

  $info  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$i]);
  //$check = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[''.$i.'Check']);
  // What's that $check for?

  $sql .= "info = '$info' where ID = $i\n";
}

mysql_query($sql)
  or die (mysql_error());
```

Running a batch of statements against the server is not uncommon and might even yield better performance than looking up the matching value in a 360 line CASE construct.